# Forwarding messages from Telegram Bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I need to do the following:

- user sends all kind of messages to my bot;
- bot should forward the particular messages to my channel like this:

  ```
  bot.forward_message(chat_id='my_chat_id', from_chat_id='my_chat_id_from_which_I_am_forwarding', message_id=message.message_id)
  ```

However, I am getting this error:

> ERROR - **init**:__threaded_polling:515 - A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message to forward not found, 2021-03-09 18:44:15,950

When I debug this, message.message_id and message.text are correct. Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: The `chat_id` should be: `in the format @channelusername` when sending to a channel

Comment: Didn't work for me. I tried both its name and the name from the link

Comment: Actually, nevermind. You were totally right. I managed to fix the problem with your help.

Comment: What was the final solution? The channelsusername format?

Comment: Yeah, I did it like this: from the link in your channel's configuration get the name and add @ as a prefix. For example, if the link is _t.me/channelname_, then the resulting chat_id is @channelname

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.forward_message(
chat_id="@channel", 
from_chat_id="chat_id_from_which_I_am_forwarding", 
message_id=message.message_id)
```

You need to add the bot as admin in the channel!!

Comment: Yes, I did just that, but I got confused with the chat_id. In the end, I got it right, but thank you nevertheless